# How to 'subtract' lexer rules in ANTLR?

Tags: parsing, antlr

Let's say I have two rules like the below:

```
printable_characters : '\u0020' .. '\uFFEF' ;

newline_characters : '\n' | '\r' ;
```

Now let's say that I want to make a new rule called `printable_no_newlines`.  I would like to do this by subtracting `newline_characters` from `printable_characters` like so:

```
printable_no_newlines : printable_characters - newline_characters ;
```

That syntax doesn't work in ANTLR3 but does anyone know what the best way would be to emulate this without re-typing the entire rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I'm also skeptical that it would do what you want: for example, your `printable_new_newlines` would include `"foo\nbar"`, since it matches `printable_characters`, but does not match `newline_characters` (as that only matches one-character strings).

Comment: Hi Martin.  I edited my example to make more sense.  I shouldn't have used .* for the printable_characters rule.  If you re-examine the question now does it makes more sense what I am trying to do?

Comment: Some of Martin's comment is no longer relevant, but the key point of it not being possible without manually writing the set difference is correct.

Comment: @Jeffrey: your edit still doesn't make the request sensible. As `newline_characters` aren't included in `printable_characters` (since they are below U+0020), anyway, `printable_no_newlines` would be the same as `printable_characters`.